# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta en PostgreSQL para sólo traer una fila por cada campo diferente?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quería preguntar cómo puedo hacer una consulta en PostgreSQL para sólo traer una fila por cada campo diferente, me hago explicar:

Esta es la tabla camisas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tabla tengo varios tipos de camisas y cada camisa tiene su color, precio y talla, pero yo sólo quiero traer una camisa por cada tipo, obvio trayendo sus demás atributos ya mencionados.

Por ejemplo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No importa  cual camisa trajo, solo importa traer 1 de cada tipo.

Gracias por su tiempo prestado.

Comment: nos muestras tu consulta?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de postgresql utilizas?

Comment: no he hecho alguna consulta y es postgres 10

Answer (score 1):

debes usar la cláusula DISTINCT en tu consulta SELECT. En tu caso sería algo así.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tipo from tablacamisas
```

Saludos

Comment: Tienes razon. No había leído en los comentarios que ya la habías contestado.

Comment: Es cierto. Mi consulta sólo trae los distintos registros del campo tipo, y no el resto de los campos como necesita el OP

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función de ventana `row_number()` para *numerar* las filas de acuerdo al `tipo` (creando particiones) y luego obtener solamente la primera fila de cada *partición*.

Algo en la línea de:

```
with 
FilasNumeradas as (
select   a.id
       , a.tipo
       , a.color
       , a.precio
       , a.talla
       --numero las filas de cada tipo
       , row_number() over (partition by tipo) as NumeroFilaPorTipo
  from camisas a
)
select   b.id
       , b.tipo
       , b.color
       , b.precio
       , b.talla
  from FilasNumeradas b
 -- me aseguro de traer solo la primera fila de cada tipo
 where b.NumeroFilaPorTipo = 1;
```

Si quieres *ordenar* la numeración de las filas por algún criterio particular, puedes incluir una clausula *order by*, por ejemplo:

```
with 
FilasNumeradas as (
select   a.id
       , a.tipo
       , a.color
       , a.precio
       , a.talla
       --acá ahora ordeno alfabéticamente por color
       , row_number() over (partition by tipo order by color) as NumeroFilaPorTipo
  from camisas a 
)
select   b.id
       , b.tipo
       , b.color
       , b.precio
       , b.talla
  from FilasNumeradas b
 where b.NumeroFilaPorTipo = 1;
```

Aclaración: No tengo *PostgreSQL* a mano, la consulta *SQL* de la respuesta ha sido escrita acá mismo utilizando *SQL* estándar, que debiera ser soportado por los motores *modernos*, *PostgreSQL* incluido.